# How to get checkbox data on form submit in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working with a checkbox in react.

I am making my checkbox using dynamic data I am getting from a server and accordingly showing checked and unchecked states on the UI.

For form validation, I am using `react-form-hook` and for getting data onSubmit, I am using `handleSubmit` from `react-form-hook`

My only issue is that I am not able to get data as per my requirement.

My data:

```
    let dta = [
    {
      p_id: 2,
      p_name: "isco",
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      p_id: 2,
      p_name: "david",
      isChecked: false
    }
  ];
```

My form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
    {dta.map((li, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id={li.component_name}
          name={`data.${li.p_name}`}
          ref={register}
          defaultChecked={li.isChecked}
        />
        <label htmlFor={li.p_name}>{li.p_name}</label>
      </div>
    ))}
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```

On Submit, I am getting data like this

```
{"data":[{"isco":false},{"david":true}]}
```

But how I want it is like below

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "p_name": "isco",
      "isChecked": true,
      "p_id":1
    },
    {
      "p_name": "david",
      "isChecked": false,
       "p_id":2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edit**

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-cohen-j55vj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: add code `handleSubmit`.for see

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur could you please explain why `let data` instead of  `let dta`

Comment: @A.R.SEIF I have added `code sandbox` with full working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am change code

```
export default function App() {
  
  let data = [
    {
      p_id: 1,
      p_name: "isco",
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      p_id: 2,
      p_name: "david",
      isChecked: false
    }
  ];

  const [dataForm, setDataForm] = useState(data);

  const changeCheck = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    let temp = [...dataForm];
    const index = temp.findIndex((x) => x.p_id === id);
    if (index === -1) return;
    temp[index].isChecked = !temp[index].isChecked;
    setDataForm(temp);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(`{"data":` + JSON.stringify(dataForm) + `}`);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        {dataForm.map((li, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={li.isChecked}
              onChange={() => {
                changeCheck(li.p_id);
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor={li.p_name}>{li.p_name}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]